# angular ui bootstrap datepicker causes "infdig"

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui, angularjs-digest

I'm trying to apply the datepicker from angular ui in my application but for some reason it results in the following error:

> Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
>   Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D

I don't understand why this error is triggered because. In the link above the description reads:

> This error occurs when the application's model becomes unstable and
>   each $digest cycle triggers a state change and subsequent $digest
>   cycle. Angular detects this situation and prevents an infinite loop
>   from causing the browser to become unresponsive.

I don't see how this is applicable to my situation at all.

If I'm using a regular input field like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="my-date" name="myDate" data-ng-model="ctrl.myDate"
                                       data-ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}" data-ng-change="ctrl.changeDetected()" >
```

There's no problem and the date is displayed just fine, but this:

```
<p class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" datetime-picker="'yyyy-MM-dd'" data-ng-model="ctrl.myDate" data-is-open="ctrl.isOpen" data-enable-time="false" data-show-button-bar="false" data-timepicker-options="ctrl.dateOptions" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-ng-click="ctrl.openCalendar($event, date)"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
    </span>
</p>
```

will result in the error. Can someone smarter than me give me a pointer as to what it is that I'm missing. I'm just loading the date from the backend and trying to display it as the current date in a datepicker.

/Regards Kris

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, apparently I'm a dumbass. there's nothing wrong with the datepicker and the code above. I had missed that the surrounding div was using a validation directive that was bound to the name attribut of the input field and I forgot to add this name attribut to the corresponding datepicker input field.